# How do I list deleted secrets in AWS Secrets Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

Looking at the [man page for `list-secrets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/list-secrets.html), there is no special options to show deleted or not. It does not list deleted secrets. However, the output definition includes a "DeletedDate" timestamp.

The [ListSecrets API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_ListSecrets.html) does not show any option for deleted secrets. But again the response includes a DeletedDate.

The [boto3 docs for `list_secrets()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html?highlight=list_secrets#SecretsManager.Client.list_secrets) are the same.

However, in the AWS console I can see deleted secrets. A quick look at the dev tools and I can see my request payload to the Secrets Manager endpoint looks like:

```json
{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
    "X-Amz-Target": "secretsmanager.ListSecrets",
    "X-Amz-Date": "Fri, 27 Nov 2020 13:19:06 GMT"
  },
  "operation": "ListSecrets",
  "content": {
    "MaxResults": 100,
    "IncludeDeleted": true,
    "SortOrder": "asc"
  },
  "region": "eu-west-2"
}
```

Is there any way to pass `"IncludeDeleted": true` to the CLI?

Is this a bug? Where do I report it? (I know there is a cloudformation bug tracker on github, I assume secretsmanager would have something similar somewhere..?)

Answer (score 6):

Save the following file to `~/.aws/models/secretsmanager/2017-10-17/service-2.sdk-extras.json`:

```json
{
  "version": 1.0,
  "merge": {
    "shapes": {
      "ListSecretsRequest": {
        "members": {
          "IncludeDeleted": {
            "shape": "BooleanType",
            "documentation": "<p>If set, includes secrets that are disabled.</p>"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can list secrets with the CLI as follows:

```
aws secretsmanager list-secrets --include-deleted
```

or with boto3:

```py
import boto3


 def list_secrets(session, **kwargs):
     client = session.client("secretsmanager")

     for page in client.get_paginator("list_secrets").paginate(, **kwargs):
         yield from page["SecretList"]


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     session = boto3.Session()

     for secret in list_secrets(session, IncludeDeleted=True):
         if "DeletedDate" in secret:
             print(secret)
```

This is using the [botocore loader mechanism](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/loaders.html) to augment the service model for Secrets Manager, and tell boto3 that "IncludeDeleted" is a parameter for the ListSecrets API.

If you want more detail, I've just posted [a blog post](https://alexwlchan.net/2021/07/listing-deleted-secrets/) explaining what else I tried and how I got to this solution – and thanks to OP, whose dev tool experiments were a useful clue.

Comment: The approach using CLI did not work for me :(  I get `Unknown options: --include-deleted`

Comment: see the minor edits above. The solution works.

Comment: the syntax is different for CLI v2: use `--include-planned-deletion` instead. https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/secretsmanager/list-secrets.html